# How to recognize duplicate row when using "load data infile"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to load data from a csv file into my database. However rows need to be *unique*, that is, rows are the same if all columns contain equal data.

My approach now is to add a new column that contains the MD5 sum of all other columns. To this end I created a stored procedure (by using information_schemes.columns) that returns a string with all the columns except the column that will get this unique MD5 sum (uniqueIdentifier).

The code for importing the data now looks as follows (I want to keep it as flexible to, on a later stage, be able to apply it to other files as well):

```
call select_all_exclude_one('vegas', 'uniqueIdentifier', @exclude_fields);

set @file_input = 'C:/MRTK_Enigma_IRD_VegaOSWP_New_Format.csv' ;
set @field_terminate = '|';
set @line_terminate = '\\n';
set @date_format = '%Y%m%d %H:%i:%s';
set @columns_input = 'deskCode, bookName, riskType, riskTypeShiftSizeInBP, productCode, currency, 
    maturity, maturityUnderlying, riskValue, currencyRiskValue, 
    issuerCategory, countryOfIssuer, ratingCategory, postDate, 
    @the_date, strike, currencyBase, indexCategory, EOL';


set @sql = concat('LOAD DATA INFILE ''', @file_input, '''

IGNORE

INTO TABLE skewrisk.vegas 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''', @field_terminate, ''' 
LINES TERMINATED BY ''', @line_terminate, ''' 
IGNORE 1 LINES \n(', @columns_input,

')\nset lastUpdate      = str_to_date(@the_date, ''', @date_format, '''),
uniqueIdentifier    = MD5(concat(', @exclude_fields,  '))');

select @sql;
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

At the end of the code, the column uniqueIdentifier (which is marked as primary key) is set to contain the MD5 sum of all the columns except itself.

However, when running this code I get the following error:

```
Action: prepare stmt from @sql
Message: Error Code: 1295. This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet
```

Questions:
1) Is there a more simple approach to what I'm trying?
2) If not, how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Define a `UNIQUE` constraint over all of the columns:

```
ALTER TABLE skewrisk.vegas ADD UNIQUE (
  deskCode, bookName, riskType, riskTypeShiftSizeInBP, productCode, currency, 
  maturity, maturityUnderlying, riskValue, currencyRiskValue, 
  issuerCategory, countryOfIssuer, ratingCategory, postDate, 
  strike, currencyBase, indexCategory, EOL, lastUpdate
);
```

Then use [`LOAD DATA IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> If you specify `IGNORE`, input rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are skipped.

NB: if the file contains the table's primary key, this shouldn't be necessary (as the PK is necessarily unique).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried executing the "alter table [..]" query, however it states:

    "Error Code: 1070. Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed".

Also, if all columns are defined as unique, doesn't that mean that if a new row is added, each column has to be unique? Because in my case, columns may equal, but only if the whole row is equal to another, I'd like to ignore it.

Comment: @NMeibergen: That is the difference between a single `UNIQUE` key defined over multiple columns and many `UNIQUE` keys each defined over one column.  However, since you exceed the database's maximum of 16 columns per index, this solution won't work for you.  Is there not some subset of columns that uniquely identify each record?

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately there is not a subset of columns that would do the job. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NMeibergen: Build a message digest of the columns, as you currently are doing, but define a `UNIQUE` key over the `uniqueIdentifier` column?

Comment: that is exactly what I was trying to do: I defined the uniqueIdentifier column as primary key and added to it the MD5 sum of the other columns. However, when running that query I get error code 129 as described in my first message.

Comment: @NMeibergen: Ah, indeed.  Can you not compose the SQL statement in your application code and send it to MySQL fully constructed?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean by composing the SQL statement and sending it to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and concatenated the row's values into the primary key column. Not one column value is unique, but the combination of the date, and the value of a couple columns ensured I'd have a unique index value and if anyone tried to import those values again, it would not allow the duplicate:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file' 
    INTO TABLE table_name 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' 
    (unique_id, date, col1, col2, ... ) 
    SET unique_id = CONCAT(date,col1,col2)
```